# SQL Server: how to return 1 row as default if condition not met

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table of messages that contains a message id field, a language id field and a text field. 
An app needs to display a message based on the id and language which together form the unique key. All messages exist for language `EN`, but not all have been translated to other languages. So for English there will always be one record selected. But if the user is French and the app needs to display message #17 and it doesn't exist yet for French, I want to return message #17 in `EN`. I would like to accomplish this in one `SELECT` query, preferably with no `IF` Statements.

EDIT: based on the answers submitted - need to clarify that every message is translated to about 10 languages, maybe more. there *should* always be *exactly* *one* row returned based on the message id and the lang id. but if that row doesnt exist, the english message should be returned.

The final code:
`declare @msgid int=2, @langid varchar(2)='fr'
SELECT isnull(xx.msg, en.msg) msgtext
FROM appmessages en
LEFT JOIN appmessages xx ON en.msgid = xx.msgid and xx.langid=@langid
WHERE en.langid = 'en' and en.msgid=@msgid`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` to achieve this

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(fr.message, en.message) AS message
FROM message_table en
LEFT JOIN message_table fr ON
    fr.message_id = en.message_id
    AND fr.language = 'French'
WHERE 
    en.message_id = 17
    AND en.language = 'English'
```

Comment: please see my Edit. need solution where lang is not hardcoded

Comment: @lkjp How do you know what language you want? You can replace 'French' with a parameter and call things that way `AND fr.language = @primary`

Comment: Thanks. that's what i was looking for.

Comment: You've hardcoded the message_id, which would only work if message_id 17 is the only one ever requested.

Answer (score 5):

A simple approach just uses `order by` for prioritization:

```
select top 1 mt.*
from message_table mt
where mt.message_id = 17 and mt.language in ('French', 'English')
order by (case when mt.language = 'French' then 1 else 2 end);
```

For a single message, performance is optimized with an index on `message_table(message_id, language)`.  The `order by` on two rows is trivial, so it should be very fast.

This approach also has the nice characteristic that it works even when some messages do not have English translations.  It is also pretty simple to add additional languages, and the effect on processing time should be minimal.

For multiple messages, you can do something similar with window functions, but that would be a different question.

Comment: please see my Edit. need solution where lang is not hardcoded

Comment: Substitute a parameter like `@lang_id` as appropriate just as you'll probably be doing with the `message_id` which isn't always going to be 17 either.

Comment: @shawnt00 . . . That is a trivial adaptation of this query -- just replacing constants with parameters.  You can have it handle as many languages as you like *at the same time*, even.

Answer (score 3):

```
DECLARE @UserLanguageID char(2)='fr',
        @DefaultLanguageID char(2)='en'

SELECT
    COALESCE(uMsg.KeyField, dMsg.KeyField) AS KeyField,
    COALESCE(uMsg.LanguageID, dMsg.LanguageID) AS LanguageID,
    COALESCE(uMsg.Text, dMsg.Text) AS Text
FROM
    Messages dMsg
        LEFT JOIN Messages uMsg
            ON uMsg.KeyField=dMsg.KeyField
WHERE
    (uMsg.KeyField=@KeyField OR dMsg.KeyField=@KeyField) 

    AND uMsg.LanguageID=@UserLanguageID
    AND dMsg.KeyField=@DefaultLanguageID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @RequestedLanguageId NCHAR(2)
DECLARE @RequestedMessageId INT

SET @RequestedLanguageId = 'FR'
SET @RequestedMessageId = 18

SELECT
    ISNULL(xx.message_text, en.message_text) AS MessageText
FROM message_table en
LEFT JOIN message_table xx
    ON xx.message_id = en.message_id
    AND xx.language_id = @RequestedLanguageId
WHERE   (en.language_id = 'EN')
    AND (en.message_id = @RequestedMessageId)
```

The variable DECLAREs and SETs are to enable you to test this.

Answer (score 0):

`declare @msgid int=2, @langid varchar(2)='fr'
SELECT isnull(xx.msg, en.msg) msgtext
FROM appmessages en
LEFT JOIN appmessages xx ON en.msgid = xx.msgid and xx.langid=@langid
WHERE en.langid = 'en' and en.msgid=@msgid`